# How to override the existing module block files in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

How to extend the block file functionality?

Because the search popular terms page shows as empty, so I have extended the block file as the following. But it is not working.

/app/code/Talk/CustomSearch/registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'CustomSearch',
    __DIR__
);
```

/app/code/Talk/CustomSearch/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="CustomSearch" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

/app/code/Talk/CustomSearch/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <preference for="Magento\Search\Block\Term" type="Talk\CustomSearch\Block\Term" />
    </config>
```

/app/code/Talk/CustomSearch/Block/Term.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Search term block
 */
namespace Talk\CustomSearch\Block;


class Term extends \Magento\Search\Block\Term
{


    /**
     * Load terms and try to sort it by names
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _loadTerms()
    {
        exit('LoadTerms');
    }
}
```

The function _loadTerms() is not called. How to extend the block in the magento-search module?

Answer (score 1):

Module name in `registration.php` and `module.xml` is not defined correctly. Has to be `Talk_CustomSearch`. Please correct and try again.

Comment: yes,  I have changed.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution!**

Change CustomSearch into Talk_CustomSearch for both registration.php and module.xml

Additionally,  I have implemented the function in the file /app/code/Talk/CustomSearch/Block/Term.php

```
protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $this->setModuleName($this->extractModuleName('Magento\Search\Block\Term'));
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
```

**Full Code**

```
<?php

/**
 * Search term block
 */
namespace Talk\CustomSearch\Block;


class Term extends \Magento\Search\Block\Term
{


    /**
     * Load terms and try to sort it by names
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _loadTerms()
    {
        exit('LoadTerms');
    }


    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $this->setModuleName($this->extractModuleName('Magento\Search\Block\Term'));
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
}
```